# Lesti FPC and Layered Navigation SEO extensions

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, ajax, full-page-cache

I have installed SEO Layered Navigetion (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layered-navigation-seo.html) and Lesti FPC.
To make the SEO Layered Navigetion work with Lesti FPC i added to Lesti FPC settings to Uri Params my filterable attribute codes. After that my filters in layered navigation is work, but when i press "Clear all" to clear filters, there is an error "An error occurred, please try again later" in Layered Navigation SEO (This error appear only when Lesti FPS is enabled).
Help me please.

Comment: Look in the var/report folder for errors, or in var/log and post the error in here if it does not give you an idea.

Comment: in var/system.log

ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1  in /home/c/cl36863/obuvnoj/public_html/app/code/community/Lesti/Fpc/Helper/Data.php on line 155

in app/code/community/Lesti/Fpc/Helper/Data.php on line 155 is: 
$regex = $pair[1];

Comment: What the vendor says?

Comment: Its both free extensions. I try to write to gordon lesti, but he is not ansewer me.

Comment: I think you should start debugging in the file indicated by the error message. See why `$pair[1]` is not set.

Comment: This is the code of error displaying:
`<?php
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<?php if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()): ?>
<div id="ajax-errors" style="display: none;">
    <ul">
        <li class="error-msg">
            <?php echo $this->__('An error occurred, please try again later.'); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about two 3-d party extensions.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue with an other module that used an Ajax call with the same URL as the page it was called from.

You'll need to add your own module with the following `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_[Module]>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </[Namespace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <[namespace]_[module]_controller_action_predispatch>
                        <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>processPreDispatch</method>
                    </[namespace]_[module]_controller_action_predispatch>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

And model `Observer.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    public function processPreDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $isAjax = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('is_ajax');

        // Check to see if $action is a Category controller
        if ($action instanceof Mage_Catalog_CategoryController && $isAjax == '1') 
        {
            $cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance();
            $cache->banUse('full_page'); // or whatever the FPC cache tag is
        }
    }
}
```